# Could not find the path of the file

Tags: c#, google-chrome, filesystems

I have been trying to access the following path to read some files from the directory but I have been unsuccessful with an System.IO.DirectoryNotFound Exception being thrown.

```
string pathname = @"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\FileSystem\000"
```

using the following code :

```
 string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(pathname);
```

However I can still locate the specified directory manually and my files to be read are still there.

Could Anyone Help Me Out On The Solutions To This Issue ?

If I cant access the FileSystem directory,how can i read the files inside that directory.

Sincerely,
Derek

Comment: Launch the process with admin previliges to get access to restricted FS.

Comment: How does your point relate to the System.IO.DirectoryNotFound Exception being thrown concerning the path to the FileSystem ?

Comment: I was referring to FileSystem cant access issue. Not to that exception.

First check if that path really exists by manually going through windows explorer.

Comment: Quote : However I can still locate the specified directory manually and my files to be read are still there. thus the path exists but why would the System.IO.DirectoryNotFound Exception being thrown then ? I cant understand that part.

Comment: Check the path again and again. Debug and see to which path the program is really looking at and if you could manually traverse there. Also as said running the program in a permissible environment matters.

Comment: @Derek please see my answer, we see you can access the directory manually, behind the scenes the Directory.GetFiles(pathname); might actuall be getting tricked into looking at a Directory that doesn't exist, perhaps because or Environment variables or etc. Once you run Process Monitor please edit your question and paste the path Process Monitor reports. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than accessing AppData\Local directly, instead could you use

```
string AppDataLocalPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
string pathname = AppDataLocalPath + "\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\FileSystem\000";
```

This should return provide the path, regardless of where the user profile resides on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path is correct:

```
string pathname = @"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\FileSystem\000"
```

Will look for that path in the root of the drive (i.e., C:\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\000) because of the first backslash.

Comment: Bro the point is not whether the path is correct or not ? I asked because my FileSystem directory cannot be accessed and how do i go about access it ?

Comment: The error you quoted was `System.IO.DirectoryNotFound` - that has nothing to do with whether or not it can be accessed.  That's a separate (permissions) issue.

Answer (score 0):

Download a tool called "Process Monitor" from Microsoft to verify what file path is actually being used: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Tip: "Process Monitor" monitors Hard Disk Drive, Registry and Thread/Process information in real time and allows you to save the traces it captures.

a. Open Process Monitor, it will start tracing information.

b. Stop the trace by clicking the Magnifying Glass toolbar button (its the On/Off tracing button).

c. Then click the Clear trace button to clear the trace.

d. Prepare to reproduce the System.IO.DirectoryNotFound Exception.

e. Then click the Start trace button in Process Monitor.

f. Quickly reproduce the System.IO.DirectoryNotFound Exception.

g. After the error has occurred, Stop the "Process Monitor" trace by un-clicking the Magnifying Glass toolbar button.

h. View the log and check the file path is correct.

**I have a feeling this will allow you to see the incorrect directory/path.**